# What is the point of returning boolean with itself?

Tags: objective-c, syntax

I have an example code that I am studying in which instead of declaring the boolean in the m file, the author did this :

```
-(BOOL) loading
{
    return _loading;
}
```

and use it like this:

```
self.loading = NO;
```

Why can't I just do :

```
BOOL loading = NO;
```

and set it like this if we need to:

```
loading = YES;
```

Comment: _loading is a class variable which can be accessed anywhere in the class using setters and getters. self.loading.

Comment: @AnshukGarg How do you know `_loading` is a class variable?

Comment: @trojanfoe He probably meant "instance" variable.

Comment: ya i meant instance variable.. normal apple guidelines of naming convention

Comment: @AnshukGarg No, Apple don't call an instance variable a class variable.

Comment: i meant by _loading having a _ for variables

Comment: @AnshukGarg you can not access class variable in instance method. it will throw variable undeclared error.

Answer (score 0):

The example is a getter method, which return the value from a property _loading.
self.loading executes a setter method, which sets the BOOL property to NO.

There are plenty of tutorials that describe setter and getter methods, example: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9fmJLaTLsok

Hope that clears things up a bit.